# Storing User and Profile in Separate tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple user model that stores an email address, crypted_password, salt and some tokens/timestamps for password recovery.

I would like to also have a more robust profile table using a has_one :user relationship. This would store things like weight and track change over time. It would also be used to store static information like height, or name.

I already have an resource for editing a user /users/1/edit where you can update your email address and password. Is it possible to have one /profile/1/edit page where you could edit your profile, update your weight AND change your user information with one save button?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rapture, Does your user table can have records with out a profile?  If so yes, you should have profile as a separate table, if not consider having profile details in the same table.. I know this is not the answer, but a clarifications coz if the schema changes this problem might never exist thanks

Comment: Thanks! Yes - the users will not be required to provide any of the profile data. So there will likely be users who do not input any information.

Comment: ok, in that case @Ireneusz Skrobis's answer is the perfect match (As you already done :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to handling multiple models in a single form then you should use something called nested form. I think the best way to learn this topic is by watching this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: awesome - love railscast and didn't know this one was out there (probably because I didn't know what to search for!) Thanks a lot.